# Redirect subfolder(s) to new domain while keeping URL with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

When I type in the URL:
`www.domainA.com/something/stockach/schwimmbad/hallenbad-stockach`

I want to redirect to:
`wwww.domainB.com/something/stockach/schwimmbad/hallenbad-stockach/`

Basically, I just need to replace the URL `www.domainA.com/something/./././` with `www.domainB.com/something/./././` but only if it starts with domain.com/something/

And I want to keep the same URL in the address bar [R=301,P]

I've tried with htaccess but we no success. What I have so far:

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?itstoolong\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/something/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wordpress-bremen.de/$1 [R=301,P]
```

Where do I go wrong? Btw. I am working with WordPress.

Comment: You seem to be negating the match on the 2nd rewrite conditional. IIRC, `!^/something/` means does not begin with. Is this intended?

Comment: No, I guess I made a mistake there. If it's domainA.com and has a folder that starts with /something/ it should redirect.

Comment: You cannot have `R` and `P` flags together. Whole idea behind proxy is to suppress new URL and `R` is for full redirect.